# Sent EOS to wrong Account From exchange Coinbase

Tags: permissions, transfer, exchange

We transferred funds from Coinbase to another coinbase account but the account name was mistyped due to autocorrect and funds went to an account called 'counbasebase' instead of the exchange 'coinbasebase'.  Any way to have them return the funds?  It's a great deal of money and now we are in panic.  Hopefully Coinbase can do something.

Comment: All funds in counbasebase are transferred to bithumb exchange, you had better contact to them.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to know about your misfortune. :(

I was checking that account and it seems that the account was parked just waiting for someone to mistype the username... you can see that the account has no activity and when it received the transfer it started to stake for resources and then move the money in 250/350/500 EOS batches to BitThumb exchange:
https://bloks.io/account/counbasebase

One can see your attempts to contact that account holder for a refund without any success as well.

On blockchain side there's nothing anyone can do, but there are things you can try to do, for instance:

1 - Contact BitThumb exchange and report this occurrence. Inform them that their user with the ID 1004927435 (from the transfers onchain) is exchanging funds that were not intended for, and ask for a block on that account and a fraud report, to attempt to get the user details and possible refund.

2 - That `counbasebase` account was created by `promotionals` account [here](https://bloks.io/transaction/be2410c921e54a967a347c3f9fbf94f156e03fcc4d4fd31bb30830942a3e7376), which in turn was created by `heztanrqgene` account [here](https://bloks.io/transaction/04c51e30128c233abab448afb4afc12591c2a840eea210ddfd0ec837efac2d14), a Binance cold wallet account. The `counbasebase` account received a transfer directly from `heztanrqgene` [here](https://bloks.io/transaction/4d74d883f15bbeabe48af1d2adafbd948c15f477a4d0d3e376c531da275679d4), maybe to simulate this, and that was almost the only action besides spam on the account since creation, so it confirms that the Binance user account with the ID 1976623641 is linked to the `counbasebase` account somehow... Maybe you can try to contact Binance and show the onchain evidence to identify the user behind this account creation.

3 - The `counbasebase` account sent a transfer to `promotionals` account [here](https://bloks.io/transaction/42d4da6ef3677247d36dedc32d5b362abf9c2a7cadccbcef0c0f45c3de08727a), who created it and many other variations of the Coinbase deposit account, with clear intention of fraud. The `promotionals` account sends funds to Binance from time to time using the ID 100193944. Maybe another user ID to explore with Binance.

Hope this information helps a bit and wish you all the luck to solve this problem. Please let me know if you were able to reach a solution or in case you need more help on this matter [here](https://bloks.io/account/prc.eos).

Comment: OMG we just saw your response. It has been over a year and we have been in great depression from this loss. Thank you so much for the information you provided. We now have new hope based on your explanation, I wish I had seen this last year. Not sure if Binance or anyone else will be willing to do anything now as it was clearly a result of Fruad. I am going to try and re-surface our case and see if Binance can do anything for us. We had contacted bithumb before (as mentioned above), but they never even responded. I will come back here and share any info we can get. Thank you again for all your